# Eclemma coverage issue for a method in an ENUM class

Tags: eclemma

I'm using EclEmma plugin for Eclipse, and the coverage report shows 0% coverage for an Enum I've defined,

```
public enum Call {
INSTANCE;

public int add(int a, int b) {
    return a+b;
}

public int sub(int a,int b){
    return a-b;
}

}
```

and my test case are like this

```
@Test
public void addTest(){
 Call.INSTANCE.add(1, 2);
}

@Test
public void subTest(){
 Call.INSTANCE.sub(1, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/oxygen3a) that comes with EclEmma 3.1.0, after ["Coverage As" => "JUnit Test"](https://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/launching.html) on "CallTest":

[image: example]

P.S. such tests without assertions are useless